# twig.controller.exception does not exist

Tags: symfony

i have a problem with my symfony project . i have this error message

> (2/2) InvalidArgumentException
>
> Class "twig.controller.exception" does not exist. in
>   ControllerResolver.php line 96 at
>   ControllerResolver->createController('twig.controller.exception::showAction')in
>   ContainerControllerResolver.php line 63 at
>   ContainerControllerResolver->createController('twig.controller.exception::showAction')in
>   ControllerResolver.php line 43 at
>   ControllerResolver->createController('twig.controller.exception::showAction')in
>   ControllerResolver.php line 69 at
>   ControllerResolver->getController(object(Request))in
>   ContainerControllerResolver.php line 41 at
>   ContainerControllerResolver->getController(object(Request))in
>   TraceableControllerResolver.php line 38 at
>   TraceableControllerResolver->getController(object(Request))in
>   HttpKernel.php line 132 at HttpKernel->handleRaw(object(Request), 2)in
>   HttpKernel.php line 66 at HttpKernel->handle(object(Request), 2,
>   false)in ExceptionListener.php line 59 at
>   ExceptionListener->onKernelException(object(GetResponseForExceptionEvent),
>   'kernel.exception', object(TraceableEventDispatcher)) at
>   call_user_func(array(object(ExceptionListener), 'onKernelException'),
>   object(GetResponseForExceptionEvent), 'kernel.exception',
>   object(TraceableEventDispatcher))in WrappedListener.php line 104 at
>   WrappedListener->__invoke(object(GetResponseForExceptionEvent),
>   'kernel.exception', object(EventDispatcher))in EventDispatcher.php
>   line 212 at EventDispatcher->doDispatch(array(object(WrappedListener),
>   object(WrappedListener), object(WrappedListener),
>   object(WrappedListener), object(WrappedListener),
>   object(WrappedListener)), 'kernel.exception',
>   object(GetResponseForExceptionEvent))in EventDispatcher.php line 44 at
>   EventDispatcher->dispatch('kernel.exception',
>   object(GetResponseForExceptionEvent))in TraceableEventDispatcher.php
>   line 139 at TraceableEventDispatcher->dispatch('kernel.exception',
>   object(GetResponseForExceptionEvent))in HttpKernel.php line 219 at
>   HttpKernel->handleException(object(InvalidArgumentException),
>   object(Request), 1)in HttpKernel.php line 77 at
>   HttpKernel->handle(object(Request), 1, true)in Kernel.php line 190 at
>   Kernel->handle(object(Request))in index.php line 37

when i go to my page. i m using symfony 4.0.11 and i  did already  "`composer require twig`"

Comment: Did you also cleared the cache ?

Comment: yes i did the cache:clear is [ok]

Comment: There is a work around [here](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/27438).  Might try a clean install.  I tried to reproduce with a fresh S4.1 project but it all worked fine.

Answer (score -3):

you may check your name's folder or file if it matches the one that you've called in your function's Controller.. :)" this was the cause of this error in my case